# Elegant way to cancel future on timeout

Tags: flutter, dart

I have these scenarios where I need to attempt something for some time or so many times, but not for too long. The `.timeout` property of the `Future` looked like a natural choice. What I learned is that the original `Future` keeps on going even after it is timed out e.g.:

```
  Future<void> trySomething() async {
    while (true) {
      print('trying something...');
      bool successful = false; // exit if done
      if (successful) {
        return;
      }
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }

  trySomething().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
    print('try something else...');
  });
```

above code produces following output:

```
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): try something else...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
```

My not-so-elegant work around was to use external flag variable to indicate to the process inside the main future that its services are no longer required:

```
  bool youAreTooLate = false;
  Future<void> trySomething() async {
    while (true) {
      if (youAreTooLate) {
        return;
      }
      print('trying something...');
      bool successful = false; // exit if done
      if (successful) {
        return;
      }
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }


  trySomething().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
    youAreTooLate = true;
    print('try something else...');
  });
```

This produces the expected result below, but doesn't make me all that warm and fuzzy inside.

```
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): trying something...
I/flutter (26426): try something else...
```

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: I believe this is happening becase you have a while(true), which will never break or finish

Comment: What are you trying to emulate? Calling an api and handling what to do during network timeout?

Comment: As far as i know the .timeout() is used for scenarios where u're awaiting an async function to return a value but something goes wrong/it takes too long so you return that value in the .timeout(), it doesn't however cancel the ongoing function.

Comment: @Rick, here's an example: there is a network resource that acts a an indicator. We need to try reading it until successful, with 1 second delays, but give up after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to do something repeatedly with a delay, you can use a `Timer` to achieve this while maintaining the ability to cancel it.

```dart
final timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
  // Do repeated work here.

  if (shouldCancel) {
    // This is the 'timer' object.
    t.cancel();
  }
});

Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10)).then((_) => timer.cancel());
```

If you're looking to actually wait for the work inside the timer to complete before retrying, you can do something like this:

```dart
Timer timer;

doWork() async {
  // Do your work here.
  // ...

  if (retry) {
    timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), doWork);
  }
}

Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10)).then((_) => timer?.cancel());
```

This should work, but if you already have an uncompleted `Future` there's no way to actually cancel it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was considering it, but if the attempt takes longer than the period of timer, the requests will collide. My preference is to have the equal (cool off) time delays between the end of previous attempt and beginning of the next.

Comment: If that's the case, you can just use `Timer(...)` and create a new `Timer` after you're done the attempt. I'll update with an example.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I think for this to work the timer has to be cancelled first thing in doWork() function because if actual work takes longer than the timer period, it will fire another copy of the function. Additionally, this may be needed if reassigning a new timer to the existing variable does not cancel the old timer. Also we need the initial call to doWork to get this rolling. By the time it works, it's not that far from my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

May not be much more "elegant," but rather than use a global `bool`, you can return a `Completer` to your caller and complete it on timeout.

```
Completer<void> trySomethingWithCompleter() {
  final completer = Completer<void>();
  trySomething(completer);
  return completer;
}

Future<void> trySomething(Completer<void> completer) async {
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (completer.isCompleted) {
      return;
    }
    
    bool successful = false; // exit if done
    if (successful) {
      completer.complete();
      return;
    }
    
    print('trying something... ${i++}');
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}

final completer = trySomethingWithCompleter();
completer.future.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
  print('try something else...');
  completer.complete();
});
```